# Qt: How to Write a Windows Desktop Utility?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, desktop, utility

I've used Qt for widget development a fair bit. That's straightforward. But how could I write a program that can be invoked from anywhere on Windows?

Say I've selected some text in a web browser. I want to be able to invoke my program via keystroke, maybe show a little list containing a list of text files I can select (ideally where the cursor is), and then add the selected text to that file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe, by writing a desktop application running in the background which can be invoked using a special shortcut key e.g. CTRL+ALT+SPACE - a unique shortcut - maybe, adding a Windows key to the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at:

- https://skycoder42.github.io/QtService/index.html
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/67043/qt-daemon